# Why won't my component's input event trigger until the component is reset?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, element-ui

I have a laravel project that uses vue. There is a very simple component that submits a simple form. But in a very strange way the input data are not reactive. The only solution I could find was to give the form a key and change it after the component was loaded. Only then the data went reactive. Normally, an input event should ve triggered and displayed on vue-devtools' Event tab, but in this component there is no input event at all (until the form key is changed). (Actually the code is simple and does not matter that much)

```
<template>
    <el-form :model="form" ref="profileForm" :key="'fix_reactive_input_issue_key'+fix_reactive_input_issue_key">
        <el-container>            
            <el-main>
                <el-row :gutter="20">
                    <el-col :span="18">
                        <el-row :gutter="20">
                            <el-col :span="12">
                                <el-form-item prop="first_name" label="Name">
                                    <el-input v-model="form.first_name" placeholder="Name"></el-input>
                                    <div class="axios error" v-if="errors['first_name']" > <span>{{ errors['first_name'][0] }}</span> </div>
                                </el-form-item>
                            </el-col>
                            <el-col :span="12">
                                <el-form-item prop="last_name" label="Surname">
                                    <el-input v-model="form.last_name" placeholder="Surname"></el-input>
                                    <div class="axios error" v-if="errors['last_name']" > <span>{{ errors['last_name'][0] }}</span> </div>
                                </el-form-item>
                            </el-col>
                        </el-row>
                    </el-col>
                </el-row>
            </el-main>

            <el-footer>
                <el-button @click="submitForm()" :loading="submit_loading" type="success" >Update</el-button>
            </el-footer>

        </el-container>
    </el-form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "profile_module",
    data() {
        return {
            fix_reactive_input_issue_key: 1,
            form: {
                first_name:"",
                last_name:""
            }
            submit_loading: false,
            errors: [],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submitForm(){
            .........
        },
    },
    mounted(){
        setTimeout( ()=> this.fix_reactive_input_issue_key++, 100 );
    }
}
</script>
```

Actually I have tried very simple basic form as well but it didn't work as well. I know It has to do with the whole project but I was not able to find it. I can use this as it is but I was wondering if any one experienced somethig like this. No @input is triggered until I refresh the form component (reseting  works as well). I was able to trigger @click event but @input is not working. I hope anyone has experienced such a thing or knows where the proplem could be.

Comment: Mind putting together a runnable MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Would make it a lot easier to help.

Comment: @AlexMA Off course you are right. And I tried but I could not reproduce it :(. I can't get nowhere the same situation. That is why I said it has to do with the whole project.

Comment: @Skeletor what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What `ElementUI` version are you using?

Comment: @sugars It was 2.0 But I am not working on that project anymore.

Comment: @Skeletor Okay, but 2.0 is already a very low version.